# Angular Warning ,Deprecated property

Tags: angularjs

I am getting some warning in my console from my AngularJs app.

```
DropdownController is now deprecated. Use UibDropdownController instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

dropdown-toggle is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-toggle instead.
2angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

dropdown-menu is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-menu instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

dropdown is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

DropdownController is now deprecated. Use UibDropdownController instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

dropdown-toggle is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-toggle instead.
2angular.js?1468622909537:11706 

dropdown-menu is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-menu instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 dropdown is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown        instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 typeaheadParser is now deprecated. Use     uibTypeaheadParser instead.
angular.js?1468622909537:11706 
$tooltip is now deprecated. Use $uibTooltip instead.angular.js?    1468622909537:11706 

popover-template-popup is now deprecated. Use uib-popover-template-popup    instead.
```

The Error is coming from `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` ,from the directive.I can completely ignore this ,if i manipulate the `ui-bootstarp.js /ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file ,but i am hoping to get some suggestions before that !. I don't want a hack but a solution.

`angular-ui-bootstrap`
`Version: 0.14.3 - 2015-10-23`

Thank You 
`sg`

Comment: Just change all the service names you inject into controllers. Add the extra `uib` as shown in tooltip warning. See docs for current service names

Comment: Doesn't help , done that,was able to solve the warnings but then the functionality is not working, for instance tried with the toggle warning , then the toggle stopped working

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem